# TextInputLayout error icon appear in both side

Tags: android

i'm working on android application for registration operations
i'm using

> compile SdkVersion 24
>
> buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
>
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
>   compile
>   'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

and the xml code for this layout is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="56dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <!-- Full Name Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_full_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Full_Name"

                android:inputType="textCapWords" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- User Name Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/User_Name"

                android:inputType="textCapWords" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--Gender-->
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RG"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/man"
                android:text="@string/Male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/woman"
                android:text="@string/FeMale" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <!--Birthday-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/input_birthday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/BirthDay"></TextView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"

                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_day"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Day"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_month"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Month"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_year"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Year"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_lable_p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="@string/Add_Contact_Info"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_medium3" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/infoContact"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- WhatsApp Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_whatsApp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/WhatsApp"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- PhoneNumber Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/PhoneNumber"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Facebook Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_facebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Facebook"
                android:inputType="textWebEditText" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Twitter Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_twitter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Twitter"
                android:inputType="textWebEditText" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Confirm Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Confirm_Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Question Password Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/QPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/QPassword" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_Q_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Q1"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--job-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RGJob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/lookjob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LookJob" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/infoLookJob"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/havejob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/HaveJob" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/infoHaveJob"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/None"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/NoThing" />
        </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attchjob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/AttachAds"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/ads_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_ads"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/attach_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Image"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/urlimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/signUp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/AlreadyLogin"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
            android:textSize="16dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

when i run it , it appeared like this 
[register layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygOKW.jpg)

java code for this field:

```
if (answerPassword.isEmpty() || Password.length() < 2 ) {
            Answer.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.ErrorAnswer));

        }
```

the error icon appear in both side of textinputlayout , why ?

Comment: edit your question and include you java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild the project with `com.android.support:design:24.1.0`. There is some issue with 24.2.1 library. using another version in my project i couldn't even get error message. So 24.2.1 is the issue. change it to 24.1.0 and rebuild.

Comment: yes it helped  , the error icon appeared at the left but i faced another problem , the  error message appeared at the right of input text layout

Comment: the output :(
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9aoDCFe6BSyNEdDcFVnNHdyRnM